# Android Unit Test start

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing

I have read many articles and tried to start a unit test using Roboelectric but i still don't get it and am not able to write a simple unit test.
Can anybody guide me what to use and how to start since unit testing in android is not easy.

Comment: Have you checked their website tutorial?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/testing/start/index.html

Comment: @Lawrance yes i checked the website tutorials and still am not able to have a clear idea

Comment: @MiguelBenitez i checked this link and its very limited i need something like a book

Comment: Do you have any problem using robotium instead of roboelectric?

Comment: @MiguelBenitez i will use whatever the do the job

Comment: Check my answer and tell me if It's easy to start with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use robotium follow next steps:

1.- Import robotium - Build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    ....
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    .....
    compile 'com.jayway.android.robotium:robotium-solo:5.6.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.0.0'
    .....
}
```

2.- Create an Abtract class to initialize your test inside androidTest package:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;

import com.robotium.solo.Solo;


public abstract class AbstractSystemTestBase<T extends Activity> extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<T> {

    public static final int WAIT_FOR_ACTIVITY_TIMEOUT = 30000;  
    public static final int WAIT_FOR_DIALOG_TIMEOUT = 30000;    
    public static final int WAIT_FOR_VIEW_TIMEOUT = 6000;   
    public static final int WAIT_FOR_TEXT_TIMEOUT = 6000;   
    public static final int STANDARD_WAIT_TIME = 30000;
    public static final int SHORT_WAIT_TIME = 5000;

    protected Solo solo;

    public AbstractSystemTestBase(Class<T> activityClass) {
        super(activityClass);
    }

    @Override
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());
    }

    @Override
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        super.tearDown();
        solo.finishOpenedActivities();
    }


}
```

3.- Create your test class which extend Abstract class (inside androidTest package):

```
public class TestMainMenu extends AbstractSystemTestBase<MainMenuActivity> {

    public TestMainMenu() {
        super(MainMenuActivity.class);
    }

    public void testMenu() throws InterruptedException {
        assertTrue("MainMenu Activity never started", solo.waitForActivity(MainMenuActivity.class, WAIT_FOR_ACTIVITY_TIMEOUT));
        //YOUR TESTS HERE

        //EXAMPLE:

         View view = solo.getView("main_menu_activity_iv_go_activity_one");
        solo.clickOnView(view);
        assertTrue("Activity one never started", solo.waitForActivity(Activity1.class, WAIT_FOR_ACTIVITY_TIMEOUT));


    }
}
```

4.- Run your test. Right click on your test class

Comment: Can u please give an example how to test a method that i written in a certain class?

Comment: Depend what the method do. In an scenario where you have a Math class which have a divide method this code works: 
SimpleMath mSimpleMath = new SimpleMath();
int result = mSimpleMath.divide(4,2);
assertTrue("result failed!", result==2); Even though I think is better using JUnit for this kind of scenario

Comment: on a sorting method that takes some parameters and return an object.
I mean how do i refer from the test to the designated method that i want to test

Comment: Is this method in the activity you are testing?

Comment: You can get the activity calling getActivity(); or solo.getCurrentActivity(); depend if you are in the activity which start the test or in other. Make a cast to your Activity class, call the method and check the results.

Answer (score 5):

I had also the same problem as before i was given the module for the unit testing in the android. This is the simple example that might help you.I  have done my best to help you.You can just run EmailValidatorTest class to see the test results. For assert(JUnit) you can follow [Assert](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html).This is XML.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#F0F0F0"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="@string/lbl_register"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#176CEC"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText_email"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/lbl_email_hint"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:padding="12dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText_password"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/lbl_password_hint"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:padding="12dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_signup"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:background="#176CEC"
    android:text="@string/lbl_btn_signup"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

This is my MainActivity

```
package com.example.hassidiczaddic.unittesting;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.example.hassidiczaddic.unittesting.R;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private EditText emailEditText;
private EditText passEditText;
private Button btnsignup;
private EmailValidator mEmailValidator;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    emailEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_email);
    passEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_password);
    // Setup field validators.
    mEmailValidator = new EmailValidator();
    emailEditText.addTextChangedListener(mEmailValidator);
    passEditText.addTextChangedListener(mEmailValidator);


btnsignup=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_signup);
    btnsignup.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            // Don't save if the fields do not validate.
            if (!mEmailValidator.isValid()) {
                emailEditText.setError("Invalid email or Password");
                Log.w("TAG", "Invalid email");
                return;
            }else
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Satrun is dead",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });




}
```

}

This is my EmailValidator Class

```
package com.example.hassidiczaddic.unittesting;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
public class EmailValidator implements TextWatcher {

/**
 * Email validation pattern.
 */
// validating email id
public static final Pattern EMAIL_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(
        "[a-zA-Z0-9\\+\\.\\_\\%\\-\\+]{1,256}" +
                "\\@" +
                "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\\-]{0,64}" +
                "(" +
                "\\." +
                "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\\-]{0,25}" +
                ")+"
);

// validating password with retype password
private boolean isValidPassword(String pass) {
    if (pass != null && pass.length() > 6) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private boolean mIsValid = false;

public boolean isValid() {
    return mIsValid;
}

public static boolean isValidEmail(CharSequence email) {
    return email != null && EMAIL_PATTERN.matcher(email).matches();
}

public static boolean isValidPassword(CharSequence pass) {
    return pass != null && isValidPassword(pass);
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable editableText) {
 mIsValid=isValidEmail(editableText);
    mIsValid=isValidPassword(editableText);
}
}
```

This is my UnitTesting In android:

```
package com.example.hassidiczaddic.unittesting;
import android.test.suitebuilder.annotation.SmallTest;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
@SmallTest
public class EmailValidatorTest {
@Test
public void emailValidator_CorrectEmailSimple_ReturnsTrue() {
    assertTrue(EmailValidator.isValidEmail("name_@email.com"));
}

@Test
public void emailValidator_CorrectEmailSubDomain_ReturnsTrue() {
    assertTrue(EmailValidator.isValidEmail("name@email.co.uk"));
}

@Test
public void emailValidator_InvalidEmailNoTld_ReturnsFalse() {
    assertFalse(EmailValidator.isValidEmail("name@email"));
}

@Test
public void emailValidator_InvalidEmailDoubleDot_ReturnsFalse() {
    assertFalse(EmailValidator.isValidEmail("name@email..com"));
}

@Test
public void emailValidator_InvalidEmailNoUsername_ReturnsFalse() {
    assertFalse(EmailValidator.isValidEmail("@email.com"));
}

@Test
public void emailValidator_EmptyString_ReturnsFalse() {
    assertFalse(EmailValidator.isValidEmail(""));
}

@Test
public void emailValidator_NullEmail_ReturnsFalse() {
    assertFalse(EmailValidator.isValidEmail(null));
}


@Test
public void passwordValidator_NullPassword_ReturnsFalse(){
    assertFalse(EmailValidator.isValidPassword(null));

    //other testcases for passwords
}}
```

Do not forget to syc your Gradle with:

```
// Required -- JUnit 4 framework
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

Comment: It was my pleasure to be of help. I had a similar problem like yours and found the solution nowhere. I will help any time if i am familiar about the topics. if you think this really helped you to understand,Please mark the answer as correct. :) :)

Comment: Hello thanks for you efforts but i already accepted the answer above before your answer so i can only up vote your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try Mockito.

Android Unit Testing with Mockito
https://www.raywenderlich.com/174137/android-unit-testing-with-mockito

With TestMe(IntelliJ plugins for Android Studio to generate Unit Testing code very easily)

**TestMe** (https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9471-testme)

Auto Generate Unit Tests for source class in Java or Groovy.
No more boilerplate!

**Features:**

- Auto-generate Java or Groovy test code with JUnit 4/5, TestNG or Spock frameworks
- Auto-generate Mockito mocks
- Generate test params and assertion statements

**Quick-Start:**
http://weirddev.com/testme/